# Getting an Error on Community When Trying to Work with Custom Auth. Provider

Tags: community, oauth, auth-provider

I've configured a community to work with custom Auth. Provider by selecting it on the manage community menu (Administration --> Login & Registration).
[image]

After entering user name + password, it goes back to Salesforce and then I get the following error in the URL:

> AuthorizationError?ErrorCode=No_Oauth_Token&ErrorDescription=Empty+Response

I've checked the Auth. Provider itself and it seems that the user has been logged-in there successfully.

Any suggestions what the problem could be or how can I debug it on SalesForce's side?

Comment: We have the same error message. Have you identity the problem ? Thks